# Which partition is better to use in a Nokia booklet 4g?

Tags: lubuntu, laptop, partitioning, nokia

I'm planning an installation of Lubuntu in a Nokia Booklet 4G, but I don't know much about partition tables and formats.

Which format would be good for the hardware?
[specs](http://www.pcworld.com/product/331992/booklet-3g.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your first Linux system and you know nothing about it yet, just keep default settings in installer — the disk will be partitioned and reformatted automatically. **Do this only if this is your only OS on computer, the data will be lost!**

In other cases use "install next to..." option in installer. Lubuntu will be installed alongside with other system on disk.